# C# : Is Variance (Covariance / Contravariance) another word for Polymorphism?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, covariance, contravariance, variance

I am trying to figure out the exact meaning of the words `Covariance` and `Contravariance` from several articles online and questions on StackOverflow, and from what I can understand, it's only **another word for polymorphism**.

Am I correct with the above statement?  Or have I got it wrong ?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It's certainly related to polymorphism. I wouldn't say they're just "another word" for polymorphism though - they're about very specific situations, where you can treat one type as if it were another type *in a certain context*.

For instance, with normal polymorphism you can treat any reference to a `Banana` as a reference to a `Fruit` - but that doesn't mean you can substitute `Fruit` *every* time you see the type `Banana`. For example, a `List<Banana>` can't be treated as a `List<Fruit>` because `list.Add(new Apple())` is valid for `List<Fruit>` but not for `List<Banana>`.

Covariance allows a "bigger" (less specific) type to be substituted in an API where the original type is *only* used in an "output" position (e.g. as a return value). Contravariance allows a "smaller" (more specific) type to be substituted in an API where the original type is *only* used in an "input" position.

It's hard to go into all the details in a single SO post (although hopefully someone else will do a better job than this!). Eric Lippert has an excellent [series of blog posts](https://ericlippert.com/category/covariance-and-contravariance/) about it.

Comment: Ah yes infact I was reading Lippert's posts, and found them quite helpful

Comment: The blog posts were all published in October 2007, I think, so they are available on this page: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10.aspx

Comment: Nope, there was another one in the series very recently ("The void is invariant")

Comment: Eric's posts on this are awesome. Might I suggest adding in to the answer a list of said links since his blog software is not working on the tags.

Comment: I'll do a bit more editing to get rid of the claim that it doesn't work :)

Comment: All links currently result in 404, so here's an updated link for Eric Lippert's blog series, https://ericlippert.com/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-1/.

Comment: @ethane: Please edit changes like that in directly. I'll do it now, but it would have been easy for you to do instead.

Answer (score 51):

Thanks for all the shout-outs, guys.

Jon and Rasmus's answers are fine, I would just add a quick technical note.

When speaking casually and informally, yes, people use "covariance" and "contravariance" to refer to a specific kind of polymorphism. That is, the kind of polymorphism where you treat a sequence of spiders as though it were a sequence of animals.

Were we to get all computer-sciency and try to make more technical definitions, then I probably would not say that covariance and contravariance are "a kind of polymorphism".  I would approach a more technical definition like this:

First, I'd note that there are two possible kinds of polymorphism in C# that you might be talking about, and it is important to not confuse them.

The first kind is traditionally called "ad hoc polymorphism", and that's the polymorphism where you have a method M(Animal x), and you pass spiders and giraffes and wallabies to it, and the method uniformly treats its passed-in arguments the same way by using the commonalities guaranteed by the Animal base class.

The second kind is traditionally called "parametric polymorphism", or "generic polymorphism".  That's the ability to make a generic method `M<T>(T t)` and then have a bunch of code in the method that again, treats the argument uniformly based on commonalities guaranteed by the constraints on T.

I think you're talking about the first kind of polymorphism.  But my point is just that we can define polymorphism as the ability of a programming language to *treat different things uniformly based on a known commonality.* (For example, a known base type, or known implemented interface.)

Covariance and contravariance is the ability of a programming language to *take advantage of commonalities between generic types deduced from known commonalities of their type arguments.*

Comment: so would it be accurate to say that (co|contra)variance are mechanisms by which you achieve polymorphism?

Comment: @EricLippert...SO WHAT YOUR SAYING IS....its polymorphic at the generic level but not polymorphic at the specific level ;)  I say its raining Cats & Dogs as long as `Rain(T:Animal)`

Answer (score 21):

You can think about co- and contravariance as being an advanced form of polymorphism. Not only can you use a child-class as if it was its parent-class, with co- and contravariance, the polymorphism extends to classes that relates to the polymorphic classes.

Imagine two classes:

```
public class Pet { /*...*/ }
public class Cat:Pet { /*...*/ }
```

Polymorphism is being able to use a `Cat` as a `Pet`:

```
void Feed(Pet pet) { /* ... */ }

Cat cat = ...
Feed(cat);
```

Co- and contravariance is used to talk about being able to use an `ICollection<Cat>` as an `ICollection<Pet>` (covariance):

```
void FeedAll(ICollection<Pet> pets) { /* ... */ }

List<Cat> cats = ...
FeedAll(cats);
```

or to use an `Action<Pet>` as an `Action<Cat>` (contravariance):

```
Action<Pet> GetFeeder() { /* ... */ }

Action<Cat> feeder = GetFeeder();
```

Eric Lippert wrote a great blog series about it when they were first designing the feature. Part one is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx).

Comment: In your covariance example, shouldn't it be `void FeedAll(ICollection<Pet> pets)` instead of `ICollection<Cat>`?

Comment: I like your post better....more color and code examples.  I like the pretty pictures ;)  So `CoVariance` is evaluated by inheritence and `ContraVariance` is evaluated the other way....as in `Contradictory`?

Answer (score 13):

I found this collection:

[Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part One](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx)

[Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Two: Array Covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx)

[Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Three: Member Group Conversion Variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/19/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-three-member-group-conversion-variance.aspx)

[Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Four: Real Delegate Variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/22/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-four-real-delegate-variance.aspx)

[Covariance and Contravariance In C#, Part Five: Higher Order Functions Hurt My Brain](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/24/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-five-higher-order-functions-hurt-my-brain.aspx)

[Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Six: Interface Variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/26/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-five-interface-variance.aspx)

[Covariance and Contravariance in C#  Part Seven: Why Do We Need A Syntax At All?](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/29/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-seven-why-do-we-need-a-syntax-at-all.aspx)

[Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Eight: Syntax Options](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/31/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-eight-syntax-options.aspx)

[Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Nine: Breaking Changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/02/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-nine-breaking-changes.aspx)

[Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Ten: Dealing With Ambiguity](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/09/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-ten-dealing-with-ambiguity.aspx)

[Covariance and Contravariance, Part Eleven: To infinity, but not beyond](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/07/covariance-and-contravariance-part-twelve-to-infinity-but-not-beyond.aspx)

Comment: yup, that's Lippert's collection

Answer (score -2):

I think is is special kind of polymorphism not another word for it. It is polymorphism in **delegates** where a delegate with a return type of base can accept child type.

Comment: no it's aspects of polymorphism in function parameters and return values. this means it affects delegates but it doesn't require them