# Understanding Covariance and Contravariance in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, covariance, contravariance

I watched a video about it on Channel 9 but I didn't really understand it much.

Can someone please give me a simple example about these that's easy to understand? After that maybe how it would be used in practice?

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/ - A collection of videos about microsoft development frameworks, and a lot more :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078423/c-is-variance-covariance-contravariance-another-word-for-polymorphism should answer a lot of your questions about it (also see Jon Skeet's link to Eric Lippert's blog.

Comment: Yeah it's like a podcast, has some really good c# vids with Anders, etc.

Answer (score 9):

You may want to look at this blog, he does a fantastic job of explaining it, but I think it will take more examples to clear it up for people, as this gets into a very hard-to-understand area, but, the quote below from the article sums it up well.

http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2008/12/c-covariance-and-contravariance-by-example.html

> "covariance and contravariance" means
>   that you can now pass inexact generic
>   types when it's safe to do so, just as
>   you can pass inexact argument types
>   when it's safe to do so.

Answer (score 8):

A `Tiger` IS an `Animal` so it can do anything an `Animal` can do. If I have a method that asks for an `Animal` I can also pass in a `Tiger`.

**Covariance** - Passing a more specific type argument

This is the direction you are most familiar with. I can pass an `IEnumerable<Tiger>` anywhere that expects an `IEnumerable<Animal>`.

---

```
static void ListAnimals(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
{
}

List<Tiger> tigers = new List<Tiger>();
ListAnimals(tigers);
```

---

**Contravariance** - Passing a more general type argument.

The 'contra' implies that this goes 'against' the normal conversion flow . This one is trickier because it seem's counter-intuitive until you see it in action.

Say I have a function which expects an `IComparer<Tiger>` and two tigers to be compared. Contravariance says I can also pass in the more general `IComparer<Animal>` because it can *also* compare two tigers (since a Tiger IS an animal). It compares them in a more general way, but this is still type safe.

---

```
static void CompareTigers(IComparer<Tiger> comparer, Tiger tiger1, Tiger tiger2)
{
    comparer.Compare(tiger1, tiger2);
}

// normal - a tiger comparer can compare two tigers
IComparer<Tiger> tigerComparer = null;
CompareTigers(tigerComparer, new Tiger(), new Tiger());

// contravariance - an animal comparer can ALSO compare two tigers
IComparer<Animal> animalComparer = null;
CompareTigers(animalComparer, new Tiger(), new Tiger());
```

---

Note that this also works with delegates. I can pass an `Action<Animal>` into a function that expects an `Action<Tiger>` because `Tiger` objects can also be passed safely to the `Action<Animal>` delegate.

Answer (score 3):

Eric Lippert came up with a very good explanation in a recent [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The following article deals with co- and contravariance with delegates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174.aspx.

Perhaps it is useful to you, even if you're not into delegates yet. I found it to be quite easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN docs for C# 4.0 (and VB) are here: [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183(VS.100).aspx)

If you are interested in concrete examples, they are here:

- [Using Variance in Interfaces for
  Generic Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465120(VS.100).aspx)
- [Using Variance in Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174(VS.100).aspx)
- [Using Variance for Func and Action
  Generic Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465122(VS.100).aspx)