# C# Casting object with inner generic

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm trying to cast a concrete class with generics to its interfaces and getting an error. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I need to get them into the common type.

> Unable to cast object of type 'HierarchalLocationFilterSet' to type 'ImAFilterSet`1[ModelBase]'.

Everything compiles and runs, I just cant seem to do something like below.

```
ImAFilterSet<IModelBase> c = new HierarchalLocationFilterSet()
```

I can go half way ok

```
var thisWorks = c as FilterSetBase<LocationModel>;
var thisAlsoWorks = c as ImAFilterSet<LocationModel>;
//This is a hard fail   
var x = ((ImAFilterSet<ModelBase>) c );
var y = ((ImAFilterSet<IModelBase>) c );
```

Given

```
public interface ImAFilterSet<C> where C : IModelBase
{
     List<C> Children { get; set; }
}

public abstract class FilterSetBase<C> : ImAFilterSet<C> where C : IModelBase

public class HierarchalLocationFilterSet : FilterSetBase<LocationModel>

public class LocationModel : ModelBase

public abstract class ModelBase : IModelBase
```

Thanks!

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance  and also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724919/understanding-covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-sharp-4-0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic classes/interfaces are invariant by default in .NET. That's why your code fails.

To cast `FilterSetBase<T1>` to `ImAFilterSet<T2>` `T1` has to be the same `T2`. Having `T1` inherit `T2` is not enough.

You can fix that by changing declaration of `FilterSetBase<C>`:

```
public abstract class FilterSetBase<C> : ImAFilterSet<IModelBase>
    where C : IModelBase { }
```

or you can make `ImAFilterSet` covariant:

```
public interface ImAFilterSet<out C>
    where C : IModelBase { }
```

That's only possible when your interface doesn't declare any methods/properties with argument typed as `C`.

Comment: Oh bummer.  I need List<C> Children { get; set; } in the ImAFilterSet<C>