# Supporting both covariance and contravariance for a single type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, interface, covariance, contravariance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Covariance and Contravariance on the same type argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528186/covariance-and-contravariance-on-the-same-type-argument)

You can declare a generic type parameter as covariant by using the `out` keyword:

```
interface ICovariant<out R>
```

You can declare a generic type parameter as contravariant by using the `in` keyword:

```
interface IContravariant<in R>
```

And you can also support both for different type parameters:

```
interface IVariant<out R, in A>
```

So why can't you suport both for a single type parameter?

Comment: James, you seem to be interested in variance today. You might want to check out my enormous series of articles and videos about how we designed the feature. They are here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/default.aspx, start from the bottom.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So why can't you suport both for a single type parameter?

Keep in mind that an interface can only be covariant in a type parameter if that type parameter is output-safe and an interface can only be contravariant in a type parameter if that type parameter is input-safe.

The syntax `out T` says that `T` is a covariant type parameter.

The syntax `in T` says that `T` is a contravariant type parameter.

As `T` is a covariant type parameter, it is by definition input-unsafe.

As `T` is a contravariant type parameter, it is by definition output-unsafe.

Therefore, `T` is input-unsafe and output-unsafe.

Consequently, `T` is prohibited in input positions, and `T` is prohibited in output positions.

Therefore, `T` can not appear in input positions nor in any output positions on any methods specified by the interface.

Consequently, `T` can not be used on the interface at all, and is pointless as a type parameter. Consequently, the language designers prohibit you from even including such a useless type marked as both covariant and contravariant on the interface to avoid the ugly

```
interface IFoo<in and out T> { }
Foo<T> : IFoo<T> { }
```

and then:

```
IFoo<Cat> cat = (IFoo<Animal>)new Foo<Dog>();
```

(If you need to read up on input-safe and output-safe, see 13.1.3.1 of the language specification.)

Comment: wow is that a hard answer to read :)

Comment: @JonH: Thanks, I tried again. Let me know what you think?

Comment: That'll do. Although my brain is starting to hurt a little now.

Comment: Actually, there are some situations in which it may be useful for an interface to include a type parameter which does not actually participate in any of the methods or properties thereof. The bigger issue is that if for any T and U derived from Object, a Foo<Object> is a valid replacement for Foo<T> and Foo<U> is a valid replacement for Foo<Object>, then Foo<U> is a valid replacement for Foo<T>.  Since covariance and contravariance only work for derivatives of Object anyway, saying that an interface was covariant and contravariant in T would render T meaningless.

Answer (score 5):

It wouldn't work.  Consider this (if `in out` existed):

```
public class INewList<in out T>
{
    public T DoIt(T item);
}
```

This would be impossible to satisfy because people expecting an `INewList<T>` would be compatible with interfaces with both narrower and wider types.

Consider `INewList<Feline>`:

If in/out both were possible, this interface would be equivalent to `INewList<Animal>` but this would be invalid for in positions because it would allow you to widen to type argument:

```
... DoIt(Animal item)
```

Which won't work because that would mean you could pass in a `new Dog()` instance where a Feline were expected from the original interface.

Similarly in reverse on the out positions because it would allow:

```
Puma DoIt(...)
```

Which would be invalid because the original interface could pass back any feline, not necessarily a Puma.

Comment: sorry i was working up my answer before i saw that @Jason already answered.

Comment: Don't apologise :-) Always nice to have a different way of the  same thing.

Comment: @James Michael Hare: Ha! And I refined my answer to include a trivial cat/dog example without seeing yours!

Comment: That is too funny @Jason!  On the same wavelength here it seems!