# C# Generics Exception, using Generics on Interface failing at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build()

Tags: c#, generics, exception, autofac

I believe I have all the interface registrations defined properly but get an exception when I call

```
container = builder.Build();
```

Exception:

> 'Common.RpcServer`2[Logic.Engine, Messages.Serializer]'
>
> is not assignable to service
>
> 'Common.IRpcServer`2[[
>
> Services.IEngine, Contracts,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null],[Messages.ISerializer,
>   Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]'.

I have very simple registration code for *IEngine* and *ISerializer* (one and none dependency respectively).

The *RpcServer* is a bit more complex but all its dependencies look to be resolving fine.

```
builder.Register(c => 
    new RpcServer<Engine, Serializer>(
        c.Resolve<ISubscription>(),
        c.Resolve<IService>() as Engine,
        c.Resolve<ISerializer>() as Serializer)
    ).As<IRpcServer<IService, ISerializer>>();
```

Is the listing of versions something I should be concerned about in the exception, or the nesting of the square braces?

> RpcServer`2[Logic.Engine, Messages.Serializer]

versus

> IRpcServer`2[[ Services.IEngine ],[ Messages.ISerializer ]]

Anything else I should be looking at to diagnose this?

Comment: Is IRpcServer marked as covariant or contravariant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Voted to close as "too localized".*

**But** if you find this question in an attempt to resolve your own issue I recommend tripple-checking all your interfaces and ensuring that they are **supporting covariance**.

Thanks to [Tim Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381938/tim-rogers) for mentioning this, one interface had slipped through, along with another very localized issue in my code base.

See also:

- [stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-4-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-4-0)
- [stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example)
- [stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/still-confused-about-covariance-and-contravariance-in-out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/still-confused-about-covariance-and-contravariance-in-out)