# Linq ToDictionary will not implicitly convert class to interface

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have the following code

```
public class TestAdaptor
{
    private interface ITargetClass
    {
        Guid Id { get; }

        string Name { get; }
    }

    private class MyTargetClass : ITargetClass
    {
        public Guid Id { get; private set; }

        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public MyTargetClass(MySourceClass source)
        {
        }
    }

    private class MySourceClass
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<ITargetClass>> ConvertItems(Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<MySourceClass>> source)
    {
        return source.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.Select(v => new MyTargetClass(v)));
    }
}
```

However this will not compile as the ToDictionary line causes the following error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Guid,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TestAdaptor.TestAdaptor.MyTargetClass>>'
to
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Guid,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TestAdaptor.TestAdaptor.ITargetClass>>'   ...\TestAdaptor.cs  38  20
```

Now it is clearly obvious that MyTargetClass implements ITargetClass but the compiler doesn't pick this up.

For now I am explicitly converting (ITargetClass)new MyTargetClass(v)

But why is this happening in the first place and is there a better way to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler wont automatically convert `IEnumerable<X>` to `IEnumerable<Y>` even if `X : Y` because `IDictionary` is not [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).  The rationale for this is discussed here: [IDictionary<,> contravariance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12841458/1224069) and [IDictionary<TKey, TValue> in .NET 4 not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2149589/1224069)

As for getting around it, like you mentioned, you'll have to cast:

With Cast extension method:

```
 kvp => kvp.Value.Select(v => new MyTargetClass(v)).Cast<ITargetClass>()
```

Explicit cast:

```
 kvp => kvp.Value.Select(v => (ITargetClass) new MyTargetClass(v))
```

**Update**:

Just to expand on this because of the confusion between `IEnumerable` and `IDictionary`. `IEnumerable` **is** covariant. `IDictionary` **is not**.

This is just fine:

```
 IEnumerable<ITargetClass> list = new List<MyTargetClass>();
```

This is not:

```
 IDictionary<object, IEnumerable<ITargetClass>> dict = 
     new Dictionary<object, List<MyTargetClass>>();
```

`IDictionary` inherits from `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. At issue is the `KeyValuePair` which is not covariant, which makes `IDictionary` not covariant.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` *is* covariant...at least from .NET 4 upwards.

Comment: @James - Good catch!  I meant to write IDictionary. Updated answer

Comment: Aha, so being covariant is they major concern here, I thought I could use an IEnumerbale in this way without trouble. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Select only reports what is being created and not a facet of the objects type. Let the select know what you are using via the [as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) keyword.

`Select(v => new MyTargetClass(v) as ITargetClass));`

It is not the compiler's job to understand an `intention` of a developer, for a class may express many interfaces. One has to provide hints to the `select` statement which ultimately brings it in line with the return object required.

Otherwise you can *filter* the elements and return an IEnumerable of the interface using [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) `IEnumerable` extension to return what is required by your method.

```
.Select(v => new MyTargetClass(v))
.OfType<ITargetClass>()
```

Comment: I suppose the real issue was not that I should explicitly declare the type but the fact that in some cases I don't have to and the compiler will actually understand the required cast. This is not an issue related to LINQ as it is the Dictionary itself that is causing the compile error. I guess my confusion is more about consistency, why can I imply the type in one case (List) but not in others (Dictionary). Anyway Philips answer explains more of this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Kezza as long as you got an answer which works that is what counts. :-)