# Is there a covariant interface for a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, covariance

```
class Animal {}
class Bear : Animal {}

class Zoo
{
    IX<int, Animal> animals;
    Dictionary<int, Bear> bears;

    void Foo () 
    {
        animals = bears;
    }
}
```

**Q** Is there a covariant interface `IX` for a `Dictionary<>`?

Comment: IDictionary<int,Animal> ?

Comment: It's impossible. A dictionary is invariant. Check out e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12841831/2846483).