# Cannot use extension method for IDictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have some already defined extension method like this:

```
    public static object Get(this IDictionary<string, object> dict, string key)
    {
        if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out object value))
        {
            return value;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

but if I try to use it with an instance of an

```
IDictionary <string, myClass>
```

it won't show up. I thought every class derived from object. Questions:

1) Why is this happening?

2) How could I make an extension method that includes all kinds of IDictionary?

Comment: You're trying to use it with the non-generic `IDictionary` interface?  By the way, [the indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2.item) (e.g. `dict[key]`) already provides what your extension method is doing.

Comment: Please provide us a [MCVE] and actually tell us what error you're getting.

Comment: Your question and goal are unclear. As is what is happening or not happening for you.

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly working:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Test", 1}};
            var result = dic.Get("Test");
        }
    }

    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static object Get(this IDictionary<string, object> dict, string key)
        {
            if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out object value))
            {
                return value;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public static T Get<T>(this IDictionary<string, T> dict, string key)
        {
            if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out T value))
            {
                return value;
            }

            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please review my question correction, as IDictionary <string, miClass> is not working.

Comment: Use a `T` generic type instead of `object` in this case (see my edit)

Comment: You are awesome! But why didn't it work out before? Shouldn't have the original extension method by available to IDictionary<string, myClass> due to inheritance? I mean, isn't myClass an object?

Comment: @user33276346 See [Covariance and Contravariance (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/), [IDictionary<,> contravariance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12841458/150605), and [IDictionary<TKey, TValue> in .NET 4 not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2149589/150605).