Covariance for value in Dictionary
I'm trying to add a more derived type as value to a dictionary<..., base> but i get the following error:
Cannot convert from HandleIntegrationEvent<TR> to HandleIntegrationEvent<IBaseEvent>
Example
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface IBaseEvent
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class UserCreatedEvent: IBaseEvent
{
    public string Name { get; } = "UserCreatedEvent";
}

public delegate Task HandleIntegrationEvent<in TR>(TR @event) where TR: IBaseEvent;

public class IntegrationBus
{
  private readonly IDictionary<string, HandleIntegrationEvent<IBaseEvent>> _listeners = new Dictionary<string, HandleIntegrationEvent<IBaseEvent>>();

  public void RegisterEventListener<TR>(string @event, HandleIntegrationEvent<TR> listener) where TR: IBaseEvent
  {
   // ERROR: cannot convert from HandleIntegrationEvent<TR> to HandleIntegrationEvent<IBaseEvent>
    _listeners.Add(@event, listener);
  } 
}

I just can't understand it and have been trying to understand the problem for some time now.
As I understand it, the generic constraint should ensure that an instance has implemented the IBaseEvent interface.
I just have a mental block in the meantime
EDIT
Found another great post https://stackoverflow.com/a/12841831 explaining the reason for dictionary covariance & contravariance.
But I'm still a bit confused

The problem is that you have the variance backwards, it's covariance that you need not contravariance. It's confusing, because delegates make the variance flip around. And in this case, it's impossible to achieve, because the delegate itself needs to be contravariant in order to allow TR to be used as a parameter.
In other words: a variable (or in this case the parameter of Dictionary.Add) of type HandleIntegrationEvent<IBaseEvent> cannot accept a delegate of HandleIntegrationEvent<TR>, but a variable of HandleIntegrationEvent<TR> can accept a HandleIntegrationEvent<IBaseEvent>.
Suppose counter-factually that it were true that it could accept such a delegate. You have a location and a function:
HandleIntegrationEvent<IBaseEvent> somelocation;

public Task HandleUserCreatedEvent(UserCreatedEvent event)
{
  ..
}

You take a HandleIntegrationEvent<UserCreatedEvent> and store it there.
somelocation = HandleUserCreatedEvent;

Someone now retrieves the delegate, and passes a different type to it
await somelocation(new SomeOtherEvent());

OOPS!
So this is not allowed. But because you are storing these delegates in a more generalized Dictionary, you don't have much option other than to do a cast check at runtime, and either throw an exception or return null.
The only thing you can do to prevent such a check is to store the actual event object with the delegate (closing over it in some way) and therefore the delegate itself knows how to handle the call. But it sounds like that isn't going to work for your use case.

You need to change the dictionary to store Func<IBaseEvent, Task> instead of HandleIntegrationEvent<IBaseEvent>. Then, wrap the listener with a Func<IBaseEvent, Task> to cast the event to the appropriate type when adding to the dictionary.
Updated code:
private readonly IDictionary<string, Func<IBaseEvent, Task>> _listeners = new Dictionary<string, Func<IBaseEvent, Task>>(); //add using System; if you get an Func<> error

public void RegisterEventListener<TR>(string @event, HandleIntegrationEvent<TR> listener) where TR : IBaseEvent
{
    _listeners.Add(@event, (e) => listener((TR)e));
}

EDIT:
Added a type check to ensure the event is of the appropriate type before invoking the listener.
private readonly IDictionary<string, Func<IBaseEvent, Task>> _listeners = new Dictionary<string, Func<IBaseEvent, Task>>(); //add using System; if you get an Func<> error

public void RegisterEventListener<TR>(string @event, HandleIntegrationEvent<TR> listener) where TR : IBaseEvent
{
    _listeners.Add(@event, async (e) =>
    {
        if (e is TR typedEvent)
        {
            await listener(typedEvent);
        }
    });
}


Until the delegate is invoked with another type that implements IBaseEvent  and you get an InvalidCastException.

Thanks for pointing that out, but a type check could be added to handle the potential InvalidCastException
