# Passing an ObservableCollection<child> to a function that take ObservableCollection<parent>

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

So I have a

```
BaseClass
```

and several child classes that inherit from the baseclass

```
ChildClass1
ChildClass2
```

I have `ObservableCollections` of child classes that need to be sorted in place, I cannot create a new `ObservableCollection<ChildClas1>`.

So i wrote a function

```
private void Reorder(ObservableCollection<BaseClass>)
{
   //sort the collection in place
}
```

then i do `Reorder(ObservableCollection<ChildClass1>)`

the compiler is complaining that it cannot convert 
`System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ChildClass1>` to `ObservableCollection<BaseClass>`

I will take the compilers word for it, but how can I achieve this without having to duplicate my reorder function for every single child type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I will take the compilers word for it

The reason why you cannot pass a collection of one type to substitute for a collection of another type is discussed in many Q&As on SO - for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3445631/335858).

> how can I achieve this without having to duplicate my reorder function for every single child type?

One approach is to make your `Reorder` generic on the type of collection element, and add a constraint to the type parameter to specify that objects must derive from your base class:

```
void Reorder<T>(ObservableCollection<T> collection) where T : BaseClass {
    ...
}
```