# Why doesn't IEnumerable of anonymous types return a List<object> on ToList()?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Here is a simplified function that I want to create:

```
static List<object> GetAnonList(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    return names.Select(name => new { FirstName = name }).ToList();
}
```

In that code block, I get the compiler error:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types#remarks) for Anonymous types, it says that anonymous types are treated as type object.  Why doesn't the C# compiler return a `List<object>` on `names.ToList()`?

Further more, why doesn't the following code cause an error?  If `List<<anonymous type: string FirstName>>` cannot be converted to `List<object>`, then why can it be converted to `IEnumerable<object>`?

```
static IEnumerable<object> GetAnonList(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    return names.Select(name => new { FirstName = name }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Anonymous types are scoped to the code block that they are created.  So you can't return the anonymous type outside of that scope which you are trying to do.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/still-confused-about-covariance-and-contravariance-in-out

Comment: The second one works because `IEnumerable<T>` is co-variant on the generic type.  The first requires you to explicitly cast the anonymous type to `object` to make it work.

Comment: @Fran you could cheat it like this `static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var items = GetItems();
    foreach (var item in items)
        Console.WriteLine(item.Index);
}

static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetItems()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new { Index = x });
}`

Comment: If you are using a recent version of C#, you should probably switch to using tuples instead of anonymous types. That way you can keep the type information throughout and not get stuck casting to object.

Comment: @RandRandom I was thinking you could cheat like Marcin's answer, but i wasn't sure. The framework isn't going to give box the results and place it into a new object for free.

Comment: Where exactly in that documentation did you see "anonymous types are treated as type object"? I don't see that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If `List<<anonymous type: string FirstName>>` cannot be converted to `List<object>`, then why can it be converted to `IEnumerable<object>`?

That's because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant and `List<T>` is not. It has nothing to do with anonymous types.

If the code you wrote was to work you'd be able to use `List<string>` as `List<object>` and add anything to it breaking type safety.

You can make your code work by passing a generic type parameter to `ToList` call:

```
static List<object> GetAnonList(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    return names.Select(name => new { FirstName = name }).ToList<object>();
}
```

But there is very little you can do with that outside of this method. You won't be able to access `FirstName` property unless you use reflection.

Comment: `unless you use reflection` or as I stated in the comment of his question the return type could be `IEnumerable<dynamic>` instead of `IEnumerable<object>`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, In response to your last concern, I am going to return the anonymous object from an MVC Controller.  Essentially, I want to return a subset of fields for another object without creating a new class.  [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-return-subsets-of-element-properties-in-a-query) is an example from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable<out T>` [IEnumerable(T) Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)

`List<T>` [List(T) Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Note that there is "out" Generic Modifier on IEnumerable interface, which allows you put more derived type to IEnumerable.

See [out (Generic Modifier) (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier)