# C# Downcasting a generic type

Tags: c#, inheritance, generic-programming, downcast, generic-type-argument

```
interface IMyEvent { }

class SpecificEvent : IMyEvent {  }

interface IMySubscriber<TEvent> where TEvent : IMyEvent { }

class MySubscriber<TEvent> : IMySubscriber<TEvent> where TEvent: IMyEvent { }

class EventPublisher
{
    public void Subscribe(IMySubscriber<IMyEvent> subscriber)
    {

    }
}
```

I can't understand why it's impossible to execute Subscribe method with a `MySubscriber<SpecificEvent>` object.

```
new EventPublisher().Subscribe(new MySubscriber<SpecificEvent>());
```

It says that it can't cast `MySubscriber<SpecificEvent>` to `IMySubscriber<IMyEvent>`. Could you please explain why it happens or provide some links where I can read about it.

Comment: does MySubscriber implement the IMySubscriber interface?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry I skipped it.

Comment: Are there any methods in the `IMySubscriber<TEvent>` interface?

Comment: @Archer, can't understand what do you mean. An object is created, but it's impossible to pass it into the method.

Comment: I changed your example calling code to match what I think you meant. Please review.

Comment: You want to make your interface contravariant I believe. `interface IMySubscriber<out TEvent> where TEvent : IMyEvent { }`

Comment: @Lee, yes, but I think it's not necessary to write them here.

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: @JonathonChase, thank you very much!

Comment: It is necessary since you won't be able to make `IMySubscriber` covariant (which would make your example code compile) if any of the methods have a parameter with type `TEvent`.

Comment: @Lee, yes, I see. I'm going to add the `void Handle(TEvent myEvent)` method, but it doesn't work. So I must find out another implementation these things.

Comment: @Lee, do you know how I can avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work you must mark the interface with an `out` generic parameter:

```
interface IMySubscriber<out TEvent> where TEvent : IMyEvent { }
```

http://rextester.com/FAXW57974

See: [still confused about covariance and contravariance & in/out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/still-confused-about-covariance-and-contravariance-in-out)

Comment: I saw your example, but it looks like it's not working there.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo well it doesnt error any more. If you take out the `out1 it will.

Comment: Tidy.  Wasn't aware of this so thanks for today's thing I've learned.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!