# How can you drop items in a `ICollection` without knowing its `TSource`?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

How can you drop items in a `ICollection` without knowing its `TSource`? I thought LINQ would be the best route for this, but I cannot figure out how it might be done with Reflection or any other method.

I am trying to implement this in a class that inherits `System.Attribute` so generic types are not permitted. And, the returned type information must be the same as the type information received on the `value` parameter of `MutateValue`. So obviously, generic would be a joy in this case, but is there another solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace Dado.ComponentModel.DataMutations
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class ApplyMaxLengthStackAttribute : MutationAttribute
    {
        private int _maxLength = -1;

        public object Mutate(object value, int maxLength, IMutationContext context = null)
        {
            _maxLength = maxLength;

            return Mutate(value, context);
        }

        protected override object MutateValue(object value, IMutationContext context)
        {
            if (value != null) {
                if (
                    value is string valueAsString &&
                    (
                        _maxLength > -1 || TryGetStringLengthAttributeValue(context, out _maxLength)
                    ) &&
                    valueAsString.Length > _maxLength
                ) {
                    value = valueAsString.Substring(0, _maxLength);
                }
                else if (
                    value is ICollection valueAsCollection &&
                    (
                        _maxLength > -1 || TryGetMaxLengthAttributeValue(context, out _maxLength)
                    ) &&
                    valueAsCollection.Count > _maxLength
                ) {
                    // Error CS1061
                    value = valueAsCollection.Take(_maxLength);
                }
            }

            _maxLength = -1;

            return value;
        }

        private bool TryGetStringLengthAttributeValue(IMutationContext context, out int maxLength)
        {
            var attribute = context?.Attributes.OfType<StringLengthAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (attribute != null) {
                maxLength = attribute.MaximumLength;

                return true;
            }

            return TryGetMaxLengthAttributeValue(context, out maxLength);
        }

        private bool TryGetMaxLengthAttributeValue(IMutationContext context, out int maxLength)
        {
            var attribute = context?.Attributes.OfType<MaxLengthAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (attribute != null) {
                maxLength = attribute.Length;

                return true;
            }

            maxLength = -1;

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You will see this code will not compile and throws this error:

> Error CS1061: 'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and  no extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This class is an extension to the [Dado.ComponentModel.Mutations](https://github.com/roydukkey/Dado.ComponentModel.Mutations) project. Definitions for other `Dado.ComponentModel.Mutations` member definitions should be sought there.

Answer (score 1):

`dynamic` to the rescue!

```
value = Enumerable.Take((dynamic)value, _maxLength);
```

There are few valid reasons to use `dynamic` in a language with such a powerful type system as C#, but it does have its occasional shortcomings, where the language designers for whatever reason (usually lack of time/resources) didn’t implement some way to express something that should be valid to express and *possible* for them to implement. However, when you hit what appears to be a rather arbitrary bump (or wall) that is simply an arbitrary limitation of the language, I think that is a perfectly valid reason to briefly abandon the type system, which is basically what `dynamic` lets you do. I believe you have hit one of those arbitrary limitations and you are perfectly justified in using `dynamic` in this situation.

If you want to make your code a little more “safe” or fool proof (should some collection that doesn’t implement `IEnumerable<>` get passed in), you can amend your else if to check if value implements `IEnumerable<>` (which you’ll have to do via reflection, unfortunately)

Comment: Awesome! This is closer. Is there then a way to cast the Enumerable return from Take to the incoming dynamic type?

Comment: No, and it probably wouldn’t be the same type anyway, but why?

Comment: Ah, I see why, you updated the question. You need to update the property with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Many extension methods in LINQ work on type `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `IEnumerable`. `Take` is one such method. Try casting to `IEnumerable<object>` like this:

```
valueAsCollection.Cast<object>().Take(_maxLength)
```

Comment: `list = (List<int>)attribute.Mutate(list, 3);` resutls in `System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type '<TakeIterator>d__25\`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[System.Int32]'.`

Comment: @roydukkey You are asking a new question now; the short answer is that an `IEnumerable<object>` is not an `List<int>`. This is a matter of variance. These links might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2184551/1937249, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3445631/1937249.

Comment: @roydukkey I'm not sure what your end goal is but you may need to reconsider your design. You are fighting the language.

Comment: Possibly, but this is due to the limitation of Attributes not allowing generic types. https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/124 I'll update my answer with more of my code and scenario.