# Custom Collection and Inherited Class Types

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections

I'm having difficulty, probably missing something simple, with queuing and unqueuing items in a collection.

I have classes with various levels of inheritance:

```
public abstract class Item
{  //stuff }

public class DetailItem : Item
{  //stuff }

public class SuperDetailItem : DetailItem
{  //stuff }

public class OddItem : Item
{  //stuff }
```

I then have a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` like so:

```
public class CQItems<Item> : ConcurrentQueue<Item>
{  //some methods }
```

One of the methods adds items when called, so I do something like:

```
CQItems<Item> items = new CQItems<Item>();
items.Generate(i);
```

It'll create `i` items in the queue.  This works, though currently in the method I am specifying creating `DetailItem` items - I'd like to have that be dynamic if possible as well, but that'll be a different question. So later, I call to get a `DetailItem` out like so:

```
 DetailItem item;

 items.TryDequeue(out item);
```

and get the message "Cannot convert from DetailItem to Item".

I don't want to make a specific collection for each inherited type.  What piece am I missing?  Thanks!

EDIT: Update for additional information.  Making `Item` an `Interface` and fixing it so that common methods were defined in the first children of the interface didn't resolve the issue, even making the collection a collection of type `IItem`.

I'm adding some details here in case I'm approaching this the wrong way entirely.  The software is a QA tool for other software that deals with banking.  Items can be `Cash : Item` (or `IItem`), `Check: Base`, `ReturnCheck : Check` and a handful of others.  Each descendant has some additional information that the class object needs to carry around that the others do not care about.  Some also require methods that their parent classes do not need.  This is why I don't want to use just a single class with all of the elements and an `Enum` for the type - different items will need to be validated differently and used differently.  For instance, when `Item` was virtual, rather than an interface, it had a field `Amount`.  It's the only field that ALL children and grandchildren will always have.

There will be some cases where I'd like to have the collection class contain some `CheckItem` objects and some `CashItem` objects. In those cases, the code that pulls items from the queue would evaluate the type of the item and work on it accordingly, as well as provide the appropriate information to the calling function.

Currently, with either the `virtual` or `interface` implementation, it KNOWS that it's say... a `CheckItem`.  But since the base class doesn't have a field for "CheckNo", when I just do `item.CheckNo`, it says the `Item` base class doesn't have that field (which no, it doesn't).

Currently I have it working by doing this:

```
IItem _item;
CheckItem item;

items.TryDequeue(out _item);
item = _item as CheckItem;
```

Which is great if there's only ever one type of object in the collection at a time.  Is this something that I cannot do, or am I approaching it incorrectly?

Comment: You can make your collection covariant or contravariant but not invariant. You say *wtf*? I know, you will need to study those terms and you will find out why you cannot do what you want to do.

Comment: Covariant is precisely my goal, which is why I used ConcurrentQueue<Item>, which is the base class.

Comment: You cannot. Not in C#. When you put more than one type into a generic collection, it is not a collection of 1 type anymore. So it is like an arraylist.

Comment: Hmmmm - interesting.

Comment: A better solution would be to ask yourself "what common operations do you want to perform on these items in the collection" and get all your items to implement a common interface. Make the collection of that interface type. Now your generic collection, is totally generic. If you have to cast things to a specific type, it is a sign for design flaw.

Comment: Revoking this comment - I read that regarding the object classes rather than the collection class.  I'll evaluate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you create a queue which is supposed to store `Item` elements.

```
CQItems<Item> items = new CQItems<Item>();
```

Then you say: take whatever concrete type deriving from `Item` you have and assign it to DetailItem variable:

```
DetailItem item;
items.TryDequeue(out item);
```

`TryDequeue` "returns" an `Item` via `out` modifier. This is basically the same thing as if you tried to assign an `Item` to a `DetailedItem` like so:

```
Item item = GetItem();
DetailedItem detailedItem = item; // compilation error
```

Which obviously makes no sense.

The "Try" part in `TryDequeue` [corresponds to the empty queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.trydequeue?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentQueue_1_TryDequeue__0__), not to the casting.

What you probably want to do is:

```
Item item;
items.TryDequeue(out item);
if (item is DetailItem)
{
    DetailItem detailedItem = (DetailItem) item;
    detailedItem.WhateverDetailedItemCanDo();
}
```

Or if your are using C# 7:

```
items.TryDequeue(out Item item);

if (item is DetailItem detailedItem)
{
    detailedItem.WhateverDetailedItemCanDo();
}
```

And BTW, it has nothing to do with a "custom collection". If you used `ConcurrentQueue` instead of `CQItems`, the result would be the same.

Comment: I think maybe I’m having difficulty understanding the way that covariance and contravariance are applied. I was assuming I could cast the out as the type of derived class I wanted it to be (or rather that it was created as). I didn’t understand, however, that dequeuing it as an Item doesn’t prevent it from still being a DetailItem. Since that’s the case, I think that’s all I need to do. My primary goal was to allow a collection to contain multiple derived types at once, if possible, and I think this would allow me to do that.

Comment: @JesseWilliams Do you expect me to add anything to this answer? If it's just the covariance and contravariance, take look at my answer to the other question. It's quite lengthy, but should help you "feel" it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53134957/672018