# Method with interface as return type, refuses to return class with implementation

Tags: c#, interface, casting, return, implementation

The method below is set to return a result implementing IResultSchema<IEmployeeSchema>.
I do that, but VS is complaining that it cannot convert the implemented classes (ResultSchema and EmployeeSchema) to the interfaces. It tells me to cast it, but the casting fails at runtime. I don't want to change the return type of the method, as the class where the method belongs, implements and interface defining the method. That would kind of ruin the point of using interfaces.
The data in "apiResponse.Response" looks perfect.
And just above the method, in the same class, I have another method returning "IEnumerable<IEmployeeSchema>" and that works fine.

The method:

```
public async Task<IResultSchema<IEmployeeSchema>> GetEmployees(int customerId, string token, int take, int skip, string direction, string column, string query)
        {
            if (token.IsTokenValid())
            {
                string endpoint;

                //Stuff for setting the endpoint string here

                var apiResponse = await CallApi<int, ResultSchema<EmployeeSchema>>(Enums.Method.Get, endpoint, token, default(int));

                if (apiResponse.HasError) return null;

                return apiResponse.Response;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

IResultSchema and IEmployeeSchema:

```
public interface IResultSchema<T>
    {
        IEnumerable<T> Records { get; set; }
        int Total { get; set; }
    }

 public interface IEmployeeSchema
    {
        IEnumerable<IApplicationSchema> Applications { get; set; }
        //Rest of the props here
    }
```

Implementations of IResultSchema and IEmployeeSchema:

```
public class ResultSchema<T> : IResultSchema<T>
    {
        public ResultSchema()
        {
            Records = new List<T>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Records { get; set; }

        public int Total { get; set; }
    }

public sealed class EmployeeSchema : IEmployeeSchema
    {
        public EmployeeSchema()
        {
            Applications = new List<ApplicationSchema>();
        }
        
        public IEnumerable<IApplicationSchema> Applications { get; set; }
        //Rest of the props here
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a Covariance issue. There should be a duplicate ... basically a `IResultSchema<EmployeeSchema>` has no "is-a" relation to `IResultSchema<IEmployeeSchema>`.

Comment: @Fildor That would make it work. I also think I understand the problem, but "Covariance" is an entirely new term for me though. I am just sad that it ruins my interface, by having to specify a concrete class as a return type. Is there are way around this? A way to implement the concrete class, but still have it work entirely with interfaces as return types. Of course, if it's now possible, I will just have to respect that.

Comment: You need to declare `interface IResultSchema<out T>` which you cannot unless you make readonly `IEnumerable<T> Records { get; }`

Comment: @Charlieface That solution works. However, I don't fully understand why. What do you think is a good read for understanding the problem/solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [still confused about covariance and contravariance & in/out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/still-confused-about-covariance-and-contravariance-in-out)

Comment: Yes @Charlieface, the answer solved my problem. Also, the links helps. Thanks.