# T to Object works but List<T> to List<Object> doesnt work at all

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello ive to following code. I know T will be always a type from the base class "Item".
But i cant cast the List to Item. For T item its working.

```
private List<Item> activeItemList;
private Item activeItem;


public void StartBuildingSystem<T>(List<T> itemList, T item, int count, string name) where T : Item
{
    UiPlacementActivate(itemList, item,count);
    PlacingAreas(GetActiveBluePrint(name), GetActiveType(itemList, name));
    activeBuildingType = GetActiveBuildingType(name);
    activeItem = item;
    //activeItemList = itemList;//
}
```

The code in // // doesnt work as i cant cast a List T to List Item. Any better approach? If i know the incoming List will be always from the base class "Item" but its coming from diffrent inventorys(Cooling, Secruity,....) or is there a way i can cast the List easy to Item List like it works for T item to Item.

Comment: Could you post the exact errors you get? It's a bit difficult to see it without knowing the exact signatures off all the methods you are using ... In general you could probably use [Linq `Cast<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast)

Comment: Look up covariance in C# -- tons of SO posts and other articles about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast between lists of various types because a `List<T>` is invariant. See [still confused about covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/still-confused-about-covariance-and-contravariance-in-out) for more (or check out the [3,000 questions on Stackoverflow about it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+covariance)).

Instead of casting, you can convert the list (by casting its items one at a time). So instead of

```
activeItemList = itemList;
```

use

```
activeItemList = itemList.Select( x => (Item)x ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can make the following change in your code, it will allow covariance:

```
private IEnumerable<Item> activeItemList; // previously List<Item>
private Item activeItem;

public void StartBuildingSystem<T>(List<T> itemList, T item, int count, string name) where T : Item
{
    UiPlacementActivate(itemList, item,count);
    PlacingAreas(GetActiveBluePrint(name), GetActiveType(itemList, name));
    activeBuildingType = GetActiveBuildingType(name);
    activeItem = item;
    activeItemList = itemList; //it will now work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mutable collections cannot implement variance. To understand why, see the following example based on your code:

```
private List<Fruit> currentFruitList;
private Fruit currentFruit;


public void StartBuildingSystem<T>(List<T> fruitList, T fruit) where T : Fruit
{
    currentFruit = fruit;
    currentFruitList = fruitList;
}
```

Let's imagine for a moment that the above code compiles (it won't). Now imagine you do this:

```
List<Apple> apples = new();
Apple apple = new();

StartBuildingSystem(apples, apple);

Orange orange = new();
currentFruit = orange; //fine!
currentFruitList.Add(new Orange()); //this is a problem!
```

Immutable collections, however, can handle this. To extend this example, if you change your `List<Fruit>` to an `IEnumerable<Fruit>` everything will compile just fine as you cannot accidentally add an orange to an `IEnumerable<Apple>`

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) is one of the better articles Microsoft has to offer on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

John's answer looks like it would work, but this is an alternative:

```
// add "using System.Linq;" beforehand
activeItemList = itemList.Cast<Item>().ToList();
```

The other answers explain this as well, but basically, `activeItemList` cannot be assigned to a List which is of a strict subtype (say `BlueItem`) of `Item`, because then, this List will be more "limited" and not be able to handle *other* non-overlapping subtypes of `Item` (e.g. `RedItem`).