# How to use IList<INeed> as function type?

Tags: c#

There is a  class :INeed, it implement the interface INeed.

And I defined a function : Func( IList needs) { }.

Although the List<> implemented the IList<> and the Need implemented the INeed,the List doesn't implement the IList< INeed>.

If I pass a List< Need > object to the function above , it won't recongnize the argument.

How to keep the function using IList as parameter type,rather than the specific Class type?

```cs
        public static async Task Main ()
        {
            List<TestNumber> numbers = new List<TestNumber>();
            numbers.Add(new TestNumber() { Number = 1 });
            numbers.Add(new TestNumber() { Number = 2 });
            numbers.Add(new TestNumber() { Number = 3 });

            Func(numbers);   // can't convert the List<Need> to IList<INeed>
            Console.Read();
        }
        public class Need: INumber
        {
            public int Number { set; get; }
        }

        public interface INeed
        {
            int Number { set; get; }
        }

        public static void Func(IList<INeed> numbers)
        {
            foreach (var n in numbers)
            {
                WriteLine(n.Number);
            }
        }
```

Comment: show code please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/still-confused-about-covariance-and-contravariance-in-out You can write a generic function `Func<T,L>(L needs) where T:INeed where L:IList<T>`

Comment: Why not create a `List<INeed>` instead?  Or if you only need to get the objects out of the collection and not put any into it in the function then you can use `IEnumerable<INeed>` instead and that will take `List<Need>` because the generic type of `IEnumerable<T>` is co-variant.