# Type arguments: accept types that inherit declared type

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have encountered something new to me.

I have an object with a type parameter

```
public class myObj<T>
    {
        ...
    }
```

Now, what gives me trouble is this kind of code not being valid:

```
public myObj<IEnumerable<string>> myFunc()
{
    return new myObj<List<string>>();
}
```

I initially expected this code to be valid, but after thinking about it I get why it's not.
My question is:

Is there any way to act on the object's declaration to make that function valid?

Googled a bit, played with where conditions on the object's declaration, but couldn't find help.
I'm thinking this can't be done, but wanted to ask more knowledgeable people

Comment: We don't see what you do with T in the class. At the moment you could simply instantiate it as `myObj<IEnumerable<string>>()`. Do you need to create instances of T in the class?

Answer (score 0):

See [Co and Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/). You need to add a covariant interface to make this work.

```
public interface IMyObj<out T>
{
    T GetT();
}
public class MyObj<T> : IMyObj<T>
{
    public T GetT() => ...;
}
public IMyObj<IEnumerable<string>> myFunc()
{
    return new MyObj<List<string>>();
}
```

Note that this is only possible as long as your interface *returns* objects of type T. If you have any method in the interface that accepts parameters of type T it would no longer work, since it would create type conflicts.

See also [still confused about covariance and contravariance & in/out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/still-confused-about-covariance-and-contravariance-in-out), or any of the many other SO questions about generic classes and variance.