# How to create List of open generic type of class<T>?

Tags: c#, list, generics, collections, polymorphism

i am working on someone else code i need to add few things
i have a class

```
public abstract class Data<T>
{

}

public class StringData : Data<string>
{
}

public class DecimalData : Data<decimal>
{
}
```

in my program i want to maintain list of different type of data

```
List<Data> dataCollection=new List<Data>();

dataCollection.Add(new DecimalData());
dataCollection.Add(new stringData());


List<Data> dataCollection=new List<Data>();
```

at above line i am getting compiler error
Using the generic type 'Data' requires 1 type arguments

Can any one guide what i am doing wrong;

Comment: Do you *need* the `generic` type parameter? I.e. does you `Data<>` class feature some `generic` methods (methods which take or return a `T`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no diamond operator in C# yet, so you can't use true polymorphism on open generic type underlying to closed constructed types.

So you can't create a list like this:

```
List<Data<>> list = new List<Data<>>();
```

You can't use polymorphism on such list... and it is a lack in genericity here.

For example, in C# you can't create a `List<Washer<>>` instance to have some `Washer<Cat>` and some `Washer<Dog>` to operate `Wash()` on them...

All you can do is using a list of objects or an ugly non generic interface pattern:

```
public interface IData
{
  void SomeMethod();
}

public abstract class Data<T> : IData
{
  public void SomeMethod()
  {
  }
}

List<IData> list = new List<IData>();

foreach (var item in list)
  item.SomeMethod();
```

You can also use a non generic abstract class instead of an interface:

```
public abstract class DataBase
{
  public abstract void SomeMethod();
}

public abstract class Data<T> : DataBase
{
  public override void SomeMethod()
  {
  }
}

List<DataBase> list = new List<DataBase>();

foreach (var item in list)
  item.SomeMethod();
```

But you lost some genericity design and strong-typing...

And you may provide any non-generic behavior such as properties and methods you need to operate on.

---

[Generics open and closed constructed types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735035/generics-open-and-closed-constructed-types)

[C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase)

[How to do generic polymorphism on open types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247604/how-to-do-generic-polymorphism-on-open-types-in-c)

[C# : Is Variance (Covariance / Contravariance) another word for Polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078423/c-sharp-is-variance-covariance-contravariance-another-word-for-polymorphis/1078469#1078469)

[C# generic inheritance and covariance part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263964/c-sharp-generic-inheritance-and-covariance-part-2)

[still confused about covariance and contravariance & in/out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/still-confused-about-covariance-and-contravariance-in-out)

---

[Covariance and Contravariance (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

[Covariance & Contravariance](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/bruceky/whirlwind-13-whats-new-in-c-4-covariance--contravariance)

[Generic Classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes)

Comment: thanks by introducing interface Idata 
then inheriting data<T> : Idata
then able to create list<Idata> i am able to achieve what i wanted. some refactoring is required i ll take care

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use generics for that.

```
public abstract class Data {

}

public class StringData : Data {
}

public class DecimalData : Data {
}

List<Data> dataCollection = new List<Data>();

dataCollection.Add(new DecimalData());
dataCollection.Add(new StringData());
```