# Is it possible to create generic classs without type argument?

Tags: c#

To my knowledge this is not possible, but I rather ask and make a fool of myself :P.

So, I have generic class `Operation<T>` where `T` is the return value of said operation. This class also tells me if an operation was successful, if not there are messages (ex. the exception message, etc.)

```
public class Operation<T>
{

    public T Value { get; set; }
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
    public string[] Messages { get; set; }

    internal Operation(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Succeeded = true;
    }

    internal Operation(bool succeeded, string[] messages = null)
    {
        Succeeded = succeeded;
        Messages = messages;
    }


    public static Operation<T> Completed(T value)
    {
        return new Operation<T>(value);
    }

    public static Operation<T> Success()
    {
        return new Operation<T>(true);
    }

    public static Operation<T> Failure(string[] messages)
    {
        return new Operation<T>(false, messages);
    }
}
```

In some cases, I only want to say that the operation was successful or not, and I don't need the `T` value.

Example pseudo code:

```
    // Example operation where I need T value
    Operation<int> op = _SumTwoIntegersService.Sum(1, 2); 
    Console.WriteLine(operation.Value); // 3

    // Example operation where I only need the operation status
    Operation op = _UserService.Add(user); // Is this possible? Initiate Operation without the type argument
    if (op.Succeeded)
        return Ok();
    else
        return BadRequest(op.Messages);
```

Comment: Generics feels like the wrong tool for the job. Would a lambda work instead? Why are you trying to use generics if you don't want the type?

Comment: Usually with result objects like this I create a non-generic base `Operation` that holds no `Value` but only success and message information. And a generic version `Operation<T> : Operation` for the operations that hold a result value. Apart from that it's not completely clear to me what you're trying to achieve, so no idea if this information is useful to you.

Comment: If the operation just has to return success or failure, why don't you just use a `bool`?

Comment: "*Is it possible to create generic class without type arg?*" => No: here you need a non generic base class or interface. See [About the lack of true generic polymorphism and the missing diamond operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570948/#58571001) • [Generics Level 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_generics.htm) • [Generics level 2](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-generics) • [Generics in .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/generics/) • [Generic classes and methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In some cases, I only want to say that the operation was successful or not, and I don't need the `T` value.

In that case, I'd basically follow the model of `Task` and `Task<T>`: have a non-generic base class with everything that doesn't depend on `T`, and a generic derived class for everything `T`-specific:

```cs
public class Operation
{
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
    public string[] Messages { get; set; }

    // Constructors, other methods
}

public class Operation<T> : Operation
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    // Constructors, other methods
}
```

Comment: @Knoop: Yup, copy/paste fail. Fixed.